# Rails Grape routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-grape

I know this is a stupid question, but I need to help

I have project with API on grape.

In my routes.rb i mount API

```
  mount API::Root => '/'
```

in **api/api.rb**

```
module API
 class Root < Grape::API
   prefix 'api'
   default_format :json
   add_swagger_documentation(
      hide_documentation_path: true,
      markdown: GrapeSwagger::Markdown::KramdownAdapter
   )

   mount Home::Users

 end
end
```

end i have rout like this

**POST /api/users/:id**

What do I need to make that route was without a prefix 'api'

**POST /users/:id**

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `prefix 'api'` line from **api/api.rb** and you should be all set.